# Is there an architecture for multiclass-classification with large amount of classes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multiclass-classification

I'm pretty new to deep learning, doing hobby projects. Right now i'm doing multiclass image classification with 200 classes. Is there a tutorial or an actual architecture i can take a look on?

So far i tried basic Dense and CNN nets, but i could never reach better accuracy than 5%.

So far my very basic CNN looks like this.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape,
                 data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (4, 4), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I looked up for solutions but could never find any project with such large amount of classes(besides VGG-19 or other SOTA CNNs, but i would try write my own, since this is for learning purposes). Is anybody had similar projects or have some tutorial or any advise on such problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

200 classes is literally few.

Try

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50

model = ResNet50(weights=None, classes=200)
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This model(ResNet50) should be good enough for most task.

Every models in keras.applications are trained to have 1000 classes, if your task is some real-world image you can use the trained weights by

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Model

model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
x = model.get_layer('avg_pool').output
x = Dense(200, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(model.input, x)
```

Comment: Well, 200 might not be a lot, but definitely a new level for me as the pictures in each class are very different. :) Thanks for your answer, gonna check it out.

Comment: "The pictures in each class are very different" means it will easier than every class are almost same. If they are really different, lightweight model like MobileNet might be enough, it much faster than other model though.

Comment: Imagine a 5 years old kid can easily tell what a car and a boat difference, but it might be difficult for even an adult to tell what year this car build.

Comment: Sorry forint my english, I meant that for Example class A contains pictures of dogs, from chiuauas to husky. Thats what I meant "different".

Comment: If you mean by, 50 species of dogs, 20 of cats, 10 of horse etc. In total 200 classes, then that's difficult. But if it's only 1 dog class, which contains many species, it's easy for Deep Learning nowadays as long as you have enough examples. You will see it after you try those large models.

Comment: Thanks for the advises, definitely.

Comment: Especially if your pictures are dogs, cats, cars, planes etc then I suggest the second method I provide. Transferring from pre-trained weights will give you much better result than train it from scratch